# Change the order of integration

Tags: calculus

I need to change the order of integration (hope that's a correct term in English)$$\int_{0}^{1}dx \int_{0}^{\sqrt{(1+x^2)}}f(x,y) \, dy$$
so we have the following intervals for $x$ and $y$: $$\begin{cases}0\leq x \leq 1 \\  0\leq y \leq \sqrt{1+x^2}\end{cases}$$
Then we can draw a figure using these intervals.\
Now lets divide y interval into 2 parts: $$0\leq y \leq 1\, and \,1\leq y\leq \sqrt{2}$$
Doing the same thing with the interval x we get two corresponding intervals $$0\leq x \leq 1\, and \, 0\leq x \leq \sqrt{y^2-1}$$
As a result we get a sum of integrals $$\int_{0}^{1}dx \int_{0}^{\sqrt{(1+x^2)}}f(x,y) \, dy=\int_{0}^{1}dy \int_{0}^{1}f(x,y) \, dx + \int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}dy \int_{0}^{\sqrt{(y^2-1)}}f(x,y) \, dx$$

What I want is to make sure that the procedure and the result are correct as it seems too easy to be correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one mistake: $y \leq \sqrt {1+x^{2}}$ becomes $y^{2} \leq 1 +x^{2}$. When $y^{2} \geq 1$ this becomes $x \geq \sqrt {y^{2}-1}$ not $x \leq \sqrt {y^{2}-1}$. So the second term is $\int_1^{\sqrt 2} dy  \int _{\sqrt {y^{2}-1}} ^{1}f(x,y) dx $